# displaying questions

Tags: sql

hello am having student data i want to display only first questions of respective candidates from every section...

Comment: Can you show us the result of your query, at least top 10

Comment: I won't answer this question, because the effort needed to manipulate the `status` column using string functions greatly exceeds the effort you would have to exert to normalize your table and have the section and question id numbers as separate columns.

Comment: Your `SUBSTRING()` attempts won't work because the width of a number is variable.  You would have to use a combination of `INSTR` and `SUBSTRING`, and this will get ugly very fast.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think you should redesign your table so that the numbers are columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution mimics SQL SERVER Row_Number() function. Google mysql over order by points in the right direction.

```
/*create temporary table t(can_id int,    status varchar(20));

insert into t values            
(001 ,   'section 1 question 1'),    
(001 ,   'section 1 question 2'),   
(001 ,   'section 1 question 3'),  
(001 ,   'section 1 question 4'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 1'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 2'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 3'),    
(001 ,   'section 2 question 4'),    
(001 ,   'section 3 question 1'),    
(001 ,   'section 3 question 2'),    
(001 ,   'section 3 question 3'),    
(002 ,   'section 1 question 1'),
(002 ,   'section 1 question 2'),
(002 ,   'section 1 question 3'),
(002 ,   'section 2 question 1'),
(002 ,   'section 2 question 2'),
(002 ,   'section 2 question 3'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 1'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 2'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 3'),
(002 ,   'section 3 question 4');

*/

select s.tcanid as 'can.id', substring(s.tstatus,11,11) as Question
from
(
select   t.can_id as tcanid, t.status as tstatus ,
            @sno :=if(@previd = concat(t.can_id,substring(t.status,1,9)),@sno + 1,1) as canid
          ,@previd:=concat(t.can_id,substring(t.status,1,9)) prevcanid
from t,
(select @sno:= 0) as sn
,(select @Previd:= '') as p
) s
where s.canid <= 3
```

Comment: Your query is not quite the same as mine - try putting the aliass back in and correct  the where statement it should be looking at the alias for sno

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you want the first 3 questions for every section but you are not considering the section in your query. The following query will do this job.

```
SELECT data_set.* 
FROM
(

    SELECT  temp.can_id
            , temp.Section
            , temp.Question
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY temp.can_id,temp.Section ORDER BY temp.can.id,temp.Section) as QUESTION_NO
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  can.id as can_id
                , SUBSTRING(status,11,11) as Question
                , SUBSTRING(status,1,9) as Section
        FROM samp_dat
    ) temp
) data_set
WHERE 
    data_set.QUESTION_NO <=3
```

Comment: Mysql does not have a ROW_NUMBER() function - right idea though.